# Нужна ли запятая после что в предложении "Ты что, звезда Ералаша?"

Tags: пунктуация

Существует такой мем:

```
— Начинается, *, Ералаш. Ты что, звезда Ералаша?
```

Хочу понять, действительно ли во втором предложении нужна запятая после *что*? И если да, то почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это ‟что” не является союзным словом или местоимением, а выполняет специфическую функцию — подчеркивание вопросительного характера предложения. В таких ситуациях всегда ставится запятая после ‟что”, как вы и написали (и не ставится перед, как вы и написали). Вот несколько примеров:
Ты что, не видишь следы – вон те следы перед дверью? (Роберт Блох. Человек, который кричал "Волк!".)
Ну что, теперь признал прежнего головореза Майльса? (Принц и нищий.)
— О доблестные воины, вы что, заснули там? — взывал отчаянным голосом ростовщик, гремя железным кольцом, но прошло много времени, прежде чем раздались шаги, лязг засовов — и калитка открылась. (Ходжа Насреддин.)